# Installing mailutils using apt-get without user intervention

Tags: linux, email, apt-get

While installing mailutils on ubuntu 12.04 using apt-get, there are 2 instances when manual intervention is required, first to select the site configuration and secondly to enter the hostname of the box. Is there a way to automate the installation? I need to install the package on many servers and being a n00b sys admin, I haven't been able to find a solution yet. I can make and install from source, however it has other problems. Thanx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I automate dpkg/apt-get?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702248/how-can-i-automate-dpkg-apt-get)

Answer (score 12):

You can use `debconf-set-selections` to pre-select answers :

```
$ debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/mailname string your.hostname.com"
$ debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type string 'Internet Site'"
$ apt-get install -y mailutils
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely want to look into **debconf** configuration specifics. Here's a [link that should help](http://itechnology.wordpress.com/2007/04/21/how-to-disable-debconf-for-automated-installs/).