# Ubuntu dockerfile - mailutils install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, smtp, dockerfile

I am installing `mailutils` via a `dockerfile` on an `ubuntu` image.

I do this via:

`RUN apt-get install -y mailutils`

However, on this line I get the following:

```
Please select the mail server configuration type that best meets your needs.

 No configuration:
  Should be chosen to leave the current configuration unchanged.
 Internet site:
  Mail is sent and received directly using SMTP.
 Internet with smarthost:
  Mail is received directly using SMTP or by running a utility such
  as fetchmail. Outgoing mail is sent using a smarthost.
 Satellite system:
  All mail is sent to another machine, called a 'smarthost', for delivery.
 Local only:
  The only delivered mail is the mail for local users. There is no network.

  1. No configuration  3. Internet with smarthost  5. Local only
  2. Internet Site     4. Satellite system
```

When I do exactly the same thing with a Debian image I do not get this option.

I use the `-y` prefix to handle all the yes/no installation questions when using a `Dockerfile`. How do I handle an option like this? I have tried adding a `-2` prefix.

Is there a way to skip this? Why does `ubuntu` require this when `debian` does not? I have checked and the mail functions correctly with debian despite not requiring this input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following `dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mailutils
```

The important part is setting `debconf` to `noninteractive` mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469343/installing-mailutils-using-apt-get-without-user-intervention) trick with something like

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y
RUN echo "postfix postfix/mailname string your.hostname.com" | debconf-set-selections &&\
        echo "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type string 'Internet Site'" | debconf-set-selections &&\
        apt-get install -y mailutils
```